# Scala - custom Marshaller for case class

Tags: json, scala, marshalling, spray

I'm implementing REST api for Spray framework and trying to implement response in nice json format

here is a bit if code:

```
case class Response(msg: String, APIv: String = "", requestNr: String = "")
case class Error(msg: String, errNo: String, exception: String = "")
case class ErrorResponse(error: Error, APIv: String = "", requestNr: String = "")

object Marshallers extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
  implicit val response = jsonFormat3(Response)
  implicit val error = jsonFormat3(Error)
  implicit val errorResponse = jsonFormat3(ErrorResponse)
}
```

Then for get method i'm using it like that:

```
def getRoute = get {
  path("schema" / Segment) { schemaClassShortId : String =>
    respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
      complete(
        FakeStorage.service.getSchema(schemaClassShortId) match {
          case None => new ErrorResponse(new Error("SchemaClass with ID: ["+schemaClassShortId + "] not found", EC.SchemaClassNotFound))
          case Some(schema) => new Response(schema.toString, "APIv-test", "RequestNr-test")
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Note that case class can have missing values in constructor like for example for "Response" class "APIv" or "RequestNr" might be not passed and set to empty - ("")

Such class would produce the fallowing JSON response:

```
{
  "error": { 
    "msg": "SchemaClass with ID: [wrongId] not found",
    "errNo": "1000",
    "exception": ""
  },
  "APIv": "",
  "requestNr": ""
}
```

However I would like to change 2 things:
1) Order

```
{
  "APIv": "",
  "error": { 
    "msg": "SchemaClass with ID: [wrongId] not found",
    "errNo": "1000",
    "exception": ""
  },
  "requestNr": ""
}
```

2) Not include empty objects into response at all

```
{
  "error": { 
    "msg": "SchemaClass with ID: [wrongId] not found",
    "errNo": "1000"
  }
}
```

As far as I understand I need to write custom Marshaller - however im not sure how to do it as im very new to Spray and specially Scala

Could you please show example of my case?

Comment: check this page https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change order of fields in json, just change order in your case class.

If you do not want to show fields which are empty or null just use Option with default value None, spray-json by default will no serialize fields which are None so they will no show up in json.

```
case class ErrorResponse(APIv: Option[String] = None, error: Error, requestNr: Option[String] = None)
```

Comment: Is it possible to change order of fields with changing order of parameter in case class constructer since `JsObject` is implemented with `Map[String, JsValue]` which don't give order guarantee?

Comment: it used to be ListMap but then since 1.3 they changed to Map, anyways according to Json specification order of fields is not preserved.